# Casperjs scrape DOM element looping through list tag

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

```
<div id="joblist-panel">
<ul class="list-job-box">
    <li id="row" class="row bt-gray-border job white-bg list-arrow">

        <div class="circle-outline">
            <div class="circle-job circle-color" style="background-color: transparent; border: 1px solid rgb(183, 183, 183);">
                <div class="circle-inner">
                    <div class="score-text"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#test/test1" class="job-title">title</a>
        <div class="row list-job">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div><i class="icon-glyph-111"></i></div>
                    3-6 Years
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div><i class=" icon-glyph-83"></i></div>
                    1&nbsp;Opening
                </li>
                <li class="location-text"><i class=" icon-glyph-14"></i>
                    Bengaluru
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Have content like this and I want to loop all 'li' tag and get href of 'a' tag and innertext of list-job class .. How can we achieve this by casperjs, phantomjs

Comment: Please show the code you already have. Something's not working? Ask specifically while chowing the code.

Comment: Do you want to loop through all `li` elements (including the nested `li` elements)? There is only one `a` element shown in your sample. Are all `a` elements located at this same level in the HTML? Also, are there multiple `.list-job-box` elements, and are they all located within one `#joblist-panel` element or are there multiple `#joblist-panel` elements?